# Error while creating date column in tables- teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

```
proc sql;
connect to teradata as tera(mode=teradata server=oneview user="&teraid." password="&terapwd.");

execute(CREATE MULTISET TABLE UD497.PAN_AM_EMAIL
(
    ATHNUM        DECIMAL(10,0),
    BLK_1_CDE      CHAR(1),
    BLK_2_CDE      CHAR(1),
    OPEN_DT         DATE,
    LANGUAGE      CHAR(7),
    MKTCELL       CHAR(2),
    PROJECT_ID     CHAR(15),
    CAMPAIGN        CHAR(35);
) PRIMARY INDEX(ATHNUM);
) by tera;
```

Error Message :

> ERROR: Teradata execute: Syntax error, expected something like a 'CHECK' keyword between ',' and the 'LANGUAGE' keyword.

Comment: Teradata <> MySQL, I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message suggests that **LANGUAGE** is a keyword in Teradata, simply double quote it:

```
"LANGUAGE"      CHAR(7),
```

But now, whenever you use it in SQL, you must double quote it, e.g.

```
select "LANGUAGE"...
```

Maybe simply change the name.

Comment: Got it, Thanks so much